# Rails 4.0.0, Gemfile requires rake 10.1.0 for Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rake

I am currently running Rails 4.0.0, ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0], with Rake 10.1.1

I was working on an app for a class in Rails, when I went to run the rake DB migration, I was given the following error message:

```
Joses-MacBook-Air:crumblr JRV$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.1.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.1.0. Using      bundle exec may solve this.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block   in setup'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top    (required)>'
/Users/JRV/crumblr/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/JRV/crumblr/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/JRV/crumblr/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is the solution to either revert or override this issue to allow for a migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like it suggests, you can do `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

For a solution that wouldn't require adding the prefix, try doing `bundle update rake`

Comment: I was having OP's issue while working with Octopress. Running `bundle update rake` worked for me.